# How to diagnose load balancer fault

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing

I have an apache2 load balancer connected to two servers. Over the past month I have noticed that the load balancer gives preference to one server over the over even though there is no balance defined. I was wondering how I would go about diagnosing this problem. I have checked the error logs well what information there is mainly relates to requests for pages. Is there anything I can do to diagnose the problem?